# Can a class have a member that is another with the same name in the same namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have two classes with the same name in the same namespace in two different files.

This is so I can construct another object with each of the two classes, following the same interface but with some functions that behave differently.

For the differently behaving functions, I will redefine them in one instance of the class.

For the functions behaving the same way, I want to construct an instance of the other class and forward calls.

Is there a way to do this? Clearly I can't have two classes in the same namespace, but perhaps I can redefine the namespace/classname of the class I want to be a member in order to forward calls?

For example:

```
//file_1.h
namespace x {
 class y {
 }
}

//file_2.h
#include "file_1.h"
namespace x {
  class y {
    // member of same class in the other file
    y memberName;
  }
}
```

Comment: No that would be ambiguous. For what would you need that? Sounds like you try to solve a XY problem for me.

Comment: It sounds to me like your looking for a common interface with 2 derived classes.

Comment: C# has partial classes (and extension methods), but C++ does not have that capability.  If you really are trying to make two different classes with the same name in the same namespace, that won't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can not modify a class after it has been declared and you can not declare two different classes with the same name.

You can declare a class hierarchy with virtual methods and use a pointer to the base. For example:

```
class A {
public:
  virtual void f() = 0;
};
class B : public A {
  void f() override {std::cout << "B" << std::endl;}
};
class C : public A {
  void f() override {std::cout << "C" << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
  A *a1 = new B;
  A *a2 = new C;
  a1->f(); // B
  a2->f(); // C
  return 0;
}
```

Although both `a1`, `a2` are pointers to `A`, the code will print:

```
B
C
```

If you do not want to made this class hierarchy public, you can use the [pimpl technique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl). It allows you to hide the real implementation of a class.
For example:

```
// File: A.h
class A {
  class AImpl;
  std::unique_ptr<AImpl> m_pimpl;
public:
  explicit A();
  void f();
};

// File A.cpp
class A::AImpl {
public:
  void f() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl;};
};

A::A() : m_pimpl(new AImpl) {
}

void A::f() {
  m_pimpl->f();
}
```

Now, you can define inside your cpp file the implementation of class AImpl. You can even use a class hierarchy for `AImpl` to create different behaving objects depending on the class that you have created internally.

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose I have two classes with the same name in the same namespace in two different files.

Then you have violated a rule called thd ODR or one definition rule.  Doing so makes your program ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

If you have a class `Alice` that wants tomuse another class `Bob`, but you want two different definitions for how `Bob` works, the solutions are called "polymorphism".

Polymorphism is the ability for two or more classes to substitute for one.

There are three simple forms of polymorphism.  There is using a virtual interface and runtime polymorphism.  There is using templates and compile time pokymorphism.  Then there is type erasures via function pointers.

The easiest is defining a virtual interface.

```
struct IBob {
  virtual int count() const = 0;
  virtual ~IBob() {}
};
struct Alice {
  std::unique_ptr<IBob> my_bob = nullptr;
  void do_stuff() const {
    if(my_bob) std::cout << "Count is:" << my_bob->count() <<"\n";
  }
};
```

now we can define two implementations of `IBob`:

```
struct Bob0:IBob{
  int count() const final { return 7; }
};
struct Bob1:IBob{
  std::unique_ptr<IBob> pBob;
  int count() const final {
    if(pBob) return pBob->count()*2 +1;
    else return 1;
  }
};
```

now `Bob1` has a `IBob`, and it uses that `IBob` to implement its own `count`.

The template way looks like:

```
template<class Bob>
struct Alice {
  Bob my_bob;
  void do_stuff() const {
    std::cout << "Count is:" << my_bob.count() <<"\n";
  }
};
```

and the various `Bob` implementations need no `virtual` or inheritance.  Here you must pick which `Bob` at compile time at each point of use.

The manual function pointer type erasure solution is more complex. I'd advise against it.

Answer (score 0):

When you include a file is like adding the content to that cpp file.
So that means you will have the same name for different classes.

There is a possibility to use the same name by using typedef.

```
class A {
public:
    static void func() {}
};

class B {
public:
    static void func() {}
};

void funcA() {
    typedef A C;
    C::func();
}

void funcB() {
    typedef B C;
    C::func();
}

int main()
{
  funcA();
  funcB();
  return 0;
}
```